# How to use this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle for background-color

Tags: html, css, angular5

I have getting error like **WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value [object Object] (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).**
How to solve this warning.

I have tried this.

In my component.ts

```
var safestyleClr = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this.itemSetDetails[i].color);
this.itemSetDetails[i].color =safestyleClr;
```

In my component.html,

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': data.color}"
```

I have also tried,

```
[style.background]= data.color
```

Still I couldn't solve this issue,can anyone please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `[ngStyle]="{'background-color': this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(data.color)}"`

Comment: @A.Sakkeer I have tried this too. But it is not working.

Comment: @keerthi Did you find a solution?